# flutter: fcm android push notifications doesn't work in release mode and work in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm using flutter sdk 3.3.5
and firebase android

firebase_core: 2.1.1
firebase_crashlytics: 3.0.4
firebase_messaging: 14.0.3

im using firebase messaging in my project
it work fine in my case in debug mood
I added SHA-1 and SHA-256 from google play
and added google service

it work fine in debug mode and give me firebase token and tested it from firebase console and work fine

this is my androidmainfest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.initiummesolutions.hr_max">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
   <application
        android:label="HR Max"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

my mainActivity.java is empty

```
package com.initiummesolutions.hr_max;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}
```

my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.initiummesolutions.hr_max"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.3')
}
flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

no kotline file..

what should i do?

i tried to:
delete google-services.json and download it again
this is what print when run in release mode

W/FlutterJNI(20984): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
E/flutter (20984): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(668)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
E/flutter (20984): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(168)] Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint.
E/flutter (20984): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(396)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (20984): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(606)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
E/flutter (20984): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
E/flutter (20984): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653)
E/flutter (20984): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315)
E/flutter (20984): 
E/flutter (20984): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:518)
E/flutter (20984): 
E/flutter (20984): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:224)
E/flutter (20984): 
E/flutter (20984): #4      FireBaseMessagingService.init (package:hr_max/Helpers/firebase_messaging_services.dart:44)
E/flutter (20984): 
E/flutter (20984): #5      GetInstance.putAsync (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:62)
E/flutter (20984): 
E/flutter (20984): #6      MyApp.build. (package:hr_max/main.dart:158)
E/flutter (20984):

Comment: Did you create SHA-1 and SHA-256 in release mode and then add those to firebase?

Comment: @ZakariaHossain i add SHA-1 and 256 fior :debug, release and google play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it when i removed api key in my https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

[image]