# Flutter FCM android release mode issues

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm completely stumped by this. I have been testing the final release of an app I'm developing and have come across an issue that I can't figure out how to work around.

I'm using FCM to send notifications to my users through topics. The notifications are triggered via a cloud function, sent as a data message, and displayed through the local notifications package. On IOS this works flawlessly, on Android it works in debug mode and then release mode is extremely hit-and-miss.

I have put in my SHA 1 and 256 keys (release ones not debug) which led to the notifications working when pushed through flutter run --release (release is properly set up in build.gradle to use the release mode app signing). But when built using flutter build --release and installed as an apk the fcm notifications don't come through at all (other local scheduled ones pushed from the app do work, so this isn't a permissions issue).

Strangely, today I pushed a test message from the FCM console to all Android devices, it came through along with a notification that should have come last night. Almost like it was pending in a queue and pushing the test message pushed the pending one through the queue.

I'm really at a loss of what to do, I've tried disabling shrink and setting up r8 rules. It's hard to debug as it works in any mode with the debugger attacked.

Here's parts of my config in case I've made a mistake here.

Pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^16.1.0
firebase_analytics: ^10.5.0
firebase_auth: ^4.12.0
firebase_core: ^2.16.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.7
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.8
firebase_performance: ^0.9.2+7
firebase_ui_auth: ^1.4.1
firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.5.1
```

build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Comment: Have you tried other solutions here on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74460574/flutter-fcm-android-push-notifications-doesnt-work-in-release-mode-and-work-in

Comment: I've scoured through all the threads I could find. Most suggest SHA-1 and SHA-256 to be the issue

Comment: I haven't tried the solution in that thread as I'm not sure about the process I should take to safely delete and recreate the API key as it was auto generated

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive) says "On iOS, macOS, web and Android 13 (or newer), before FCM payloads can be received on your device, you must first ask the user's permission."

You can ask user to user with this code

```
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
alert: true,
announcement: false,
badge: true,
carPlay: false,
criticalAlert: false,
provisional: false,
sound: true,
);

print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
```

Then you should isolate your background message.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
// If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
// make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
await Firebase.initializeApp();

print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
to mark a function (or other entities, as classes) to indicate to the compiler that it will be used from native code. Without this annotation, the dart compiler could strip out unused functions, inline them, shrink names, etc, and the native code would fail to call it.

There are a few things to keep in mind about your background message handler:

1. It must not be an anonymous function.
2. It must be a top-level function (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization).
3. When using Flutter version 3.3.0 or higher, the message handler must be annotated with @pragma('vm:entry-point') right above the function declaration (otherwise it may be removed during tree shaking for release mode).

You can reach more details from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clean in my initial post. I have all this included already. It used to work great prior to upgrading my test device to android 14 too. And on iOS it works flawlessly